# Type The type cannot be a superinterface of Do; a superinterface must be an interface error

Tags: java, interface, numbers, phone-number

I am a java noob. I have to program a interface that extends number.

```
public interface Sequence<T> extends Number{
 T next();
}
```

I do not know why i am getting a error under number "the type number cannot be a superinterface of Sequence". could someone tell me what i am doing wrong and how to correct this code? all help is appreciated

Comment: Looks OK to me, let me check it out.

Comment: And as Andy pointed out, `Number` is a class, not an interface, and can't be extended by an interface (only another class).  Go ask your instructor what they meant, because this is literally impossible.

Answer (score 2):

[`java.lang.Number`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html) is a class; specifically, an abstract class. Interfaces can't extend classes, only other interfaces.

You either have to implement a *class* which extends it, or the assignment is referring to some other `Number` interface.

Comment: Yup, the assignment is literally impossible as stated.  Perhaps the instructor meant to create an "interface" that is really a class (perhaps an abstract class...).